# Can no longer save changes to a Chrome extension, refresh, and see that change

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm developing an extension (in developer mode) and up until yesterday I could make a change to the extension's background page, save the change, refresh the extension, and see the change. Now presumably with version 45 that no longer works. The only workaround I found was to remove and reinstall the extension. Is anyone else experiencing the same thing?

Screencast of the problem - 
http://recordit.co/OK0zQImeQY

Comment: The steps in this post (https://goo.gl/S5rVjE) solved the problem in the screencast above. I still had to refresh the developer tools console to see the changed message, but its at least tolerable. I still can't see changes to a CSS file, for example, without removing and reinstalling the ext though.

Comment: I'm also having this issue -- definitely a major regression in behavior.